# Simple PHP embedded in some really Simple HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on getting a Raspberry pi project online. I've got some sample code writing a MYSQL database, and I've successfully got the domain pointer set up and I can get the data online using Apache. However, when I found some sample code online with ways to do these things it does not completely work for me. However, if I directly access a .php file with the database information it works.

Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong on the HTML side of things and why it won't show me the information correctly?

This is what I get.

[image: enter image description here]]

My code is this:
connectdb.php

```
<?PHP
DEFINE ('server' = '127.0.0.1');
DEFINE ('user_name' = 'root');
DEFINE ('password' = 'xxxxxxxx');
DEFINE ('database' = 'website_database');

    $db_handle = mysql_connect(server, user_name, password, database);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    ?>
```

My html site is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display Data into DB</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #FFC;
    }
th {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    }

td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="database.php">blah</a>

<h1> Display Data from DB </h1>

<?php
include('connectdb.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM templog";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($db_handle, $sqlget) or die('error getting db');

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th>";

while($column = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $column['date'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $column['time'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }

echo "</table>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great. I'm very new to this and just trying to get started with some basic functions. I'll literally have less than 15 functions passed through here so I'm not looking for many bells and whistles, just a little display and eventually a little input.

Comment: Your file needs to be `.php` not `.html`. (*Since it has PHP code present within it.*)

Comment: you are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions together. you should use `mysqli_` functions only. `mysql_` functions are deprecated for a long time.

Comment: Yes...You can't connect through a `mysql` and then later use `mysqli` functions..That' wrong and you will have errors and your code will not work..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting that you use MySQLi as mysql is depreciated.

connectdb.php

```
$mysqli = newMySQLi('localhost','root','xxxxxxx','website_database');
```

your main driver

```
<head>
<title>Display Data into DB</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table {
border: 2px solid red;
background-color: #FFC;
}
th {
border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}

td {
border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- no reason to href this    <a href="database.php">blah</a> --->

<h1> Display Data from DB </h1>

<?php
include('connectdb.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM templog";
$results = $mySQLi->query($sqlget);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th>";

while($column = $results->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $column['date'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $column['time'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }

echo "</table>";

?>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, you posted this about the same time I figured it out. Thank you regardless!

Comment: No probs, suggest that you use MySQLi to code instead of mysql_ as it is depreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys you led me down the right path. The issue was a combination of .html file, and mixing the mysqli and mysql as you guys described. Here is the final code that works just fine.

To help people in the future, this was the correct formatting.

```
<?PHP
$server = "127.0.0.1";
    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "xxxxxxxx";
    $database = "website_database";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Display Data into DB</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #FFC;
    }
th {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    }

td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="database.php">blah</a>

<h1> Display Data from DB </h1>

<?php

include('connectdb.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM templog";

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th>";
if ($db_found) {

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM templog";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);

        while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $db_field['date'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $db_field['time'];
            echo "</td><td>";

        }

    mysql_close($db_handle);
echo "</table>";
}
else {

    print "Database NOT Found ";
    mysql_close($db_handle);

    }




echo "</table>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```